# Trouble getting a master page control in a page that uses it

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a `Label` in my mater page which i want to access in a page which uses the same mater page.
I tried..

`string text = ((Label)Master.FindControl("myLabel")).Text; //Always returns empty string`

P.S i have included `<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Masters/Master1.master" %>`
 still not working

Comment: I have used this syntax quite a lot, without any issues. Spelling of myLabel? Do you have the MasterPageFile attribute in your page directive?

Comment: Did you mean `<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/Masters/Master1.master" %>`

Comment: Is `FindControl("myLabel")` returns something in your master page?

Comment: I sets the `Text` property of the `myLabel` to `"SomeText"` in Master page's `Page_Load` and when i uses the above code `Text` property is returns just `String.Empty`

Comment: @TheSuperTramp, in which event of page you are accessing the label? **Note that Master's Load event occurs after Page's Load event**

Comment: Yeah.. that that's the problem.. is there any event which fires after the master page's `Page load` which i can call from the child page's page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Waqas Raja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334494/waqas-raja) mentioned in comments, the problem is in event sequence: master's `Load` event occurs after page's `Load` event. So you could just use [`Page.LoadComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx) event in your page:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = ((Label)Master.FindControl("myLabel")).Text;
}
```

and it should give you desired value of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

i thing you label in master page reside in content place holder. so

```
 ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder = 
      (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
  string  TextBoxvalue = 
            ((TextBox) mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```